# What is the difference between large signal model/analysis and dc model/analysis?

Tags: transistors, analysis, modeling, power-amplifier, small-signal

I am studying microelectronics. I have studied about the DC analysis and the AC analysis. The DC analysis is just to find the operating point or the quiescent point and then the AC analysis is done. An AC analysis can be done in two ways for non-linear devices (like diodes and transistors): small signal AC analysis and large signal AC analysis. Small and large signal AC analysis are used in transistors amplifiers (transistors act as amplifiers in active region). I know that when we linearize the large signal model of non-linear devices, it becomes small signal signal model. But many books refer to the semiconductor device equations (like current equations or voltage equations), used to describe the behavior of the device at DC and to find the operating point, as large signal. These books refer to DC parameters such as V<sub>BE</sub> as large signal. Some sources say the term *large-signal* refers to the magnitude of the AC signal relative to the operating bias and in that case I think v<sub>be</sub> (the ac signal) should be the large signal parameter.

[image]

This pdf is made by me and shows my effort in making sense of the large signal analysis and large signal parameters which are used interchangeably with dc analysis and dc parameters most of the time (I don't know why. Is it because both DC model and large signal AC model use the accurate non-linear equations for analysis and hence we have **Large Signal DC Model** and **Large Signal AC Model**?).

Based on my current understanding, I have come up with some points which are shown through the example of a diode in link below:
[Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jXn_uMd4UuPJi1hBh_9hcdTcDs0ppLge/view)

Please provide your valuable feedback.

Please let me know if I understand it right:

1. Large signal models do both ac and dc analysis.
2. Large signal models are also called dc models or large signal dc models.
3. Small signal models do only ac analysis after doing dc analysis separately (due to superposition due to linearity).
4. Large signals models are done mostly using simulation and referred to as transient analysis.
5. Small signal analysis is a specific case of large signal models at a specific operating point to assume linearity.
6. DC biasing circuits (done simultaneously with large signal models and done separately with small signal ac models[due to superposition]) are obtained from large signal models at zero frequency (neglecting effects of capacitors and inductors).
7. All DC parameters can be referred to as large signal parameters.

Comment: Please don't ask readers to click through to another document. Your question will also lose any value if your document is deleted. Summarize your (one or two) key questions here.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I tried to put all my main points here itself. The document is just to show an example of my understanding and my effort, in case the question remains unclear.

Comment: *The DC analysis is just to find the operating point or the quiescent point and then the AC analysis is done.* No. Without the DC analysis, doing any **large signal** or **transient** simulation would be impossible. Explain how you would simulate the clipping behavior of an amplifier without using a DC simulation. Remember that I mentioned that the transient simulation makes use of the DC simulation.

Comment: *Large Signal AC Model* No such thing exists, the large signal (DC) models are sufficient. Then inductors and capacitors are added to those models to take into account the respose to variations over time (transient behavior). Realize that the **small signal AC** analysis / models are simply the **time derivative** of the (large signal) DC models at a certain steady-state solution (operating point).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie First of all, thank you for your valuable feedback. The insights you provided are very helpful. I have been scratching my head about these things from last few days. An edit has been made based on pointers which I made from knowledge provided by you and myself. Please review the edit.

Comment: Also I have question that why DC parameters such as $$
V_{B E}
$$ should be referred as large signal and why not either $$
v_{B E}
$$ or$$
v_{b e}
$$ are large signal? $$
v_{B E}=V_{B E}+v_{b e}
$$                  I say it because I thought it is the ac input which is large, so $$
v_{b e}$$ should be large signal value.                             
Like  $$
v_{b e}$$ is small signal value for small signal ac analysis.

Comment: \$V_{BE}\$ is the (large signal) DC value. like 0.6 V. \$v_{BE}\$ is the small signal derivative of \$V_{BE}\$. That \$_{be}\$ doesn't mean anything so \$v_{be}\$ has no meaning. Maybe some articles would use \$V_{be}\$ and \$v_{be}\$ but then \$V_{be}\$ = \$V_{BE}\$ and \$v_{be}\$ = \$v_{BE}\$. BE or be simply stands for **B**ase-**E**mitter.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The meaning of all these symbols are given in my post. And $$
v_{b e}
$$ is the ac voltage. In small signal analysis, this parameter is called small signal ac voltage so in dc analysis, should not this parameter be called large signal ac voltage? Why DC voltage is being called as large signal voltage?                                         Also please review the edit made by me and tell if the pointers are correct or not.

Comment: These notations are standard in all microelectronics books (I study Sedra/Smith and Donald Neamen).

Comment: $$
v_{B E}=V_{B E}+v_{b e}
$$

$$
V_{B E} \neq V_{b e}
$$

$$
v_{B E} \neq v_{b e}
$$

Comment: Is this equation vBE=VBE+vbe valid only for small signal ac analysis?                                                  Also is there a fixed quiescent or operating point for large signal analysis like small signal ac analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Large signal models are also called dc models or large signal dc models.

Not always.

DC models neglect capacitance and inductance.

Therefore a large-signal AC model must have additional components that are not included in a DC model.

> Large signals models are done mostly using simulation and referred to as transient analysis.

There are other kinds of large signal AC analysis besides transient. For example, harmonic balance analysis.

> Small signal analysis is a specific case of large signal models at a specific operating point to assume linearity.

I wouldn't say it's a specific case of a large signal model. I'd say it's a reduction of a large signal model by neglecting non-linear effects. It's what physicists call a perturbation model.